# I cannot get thunderbird to connect to Outlook.com

Tags: email, thunderbird, outlook.com

Had to reformat my pc and have been unable to get Thunderbird to connect to my Outlook.com account again. I have no problem connecting to Yahoo. Using Windows 7 and have checked and double checked my in and outgoing server settings and they are correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific error message it's giving you?

Comment: Login to server smtp-mail.outlook.com failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
1.       Open Thunderbird.
2.       From the Application menu, choose Add Account…
3.       Input your account information, choose Options… then Account Settings…
4.       Click the Account Actions button, then choose Add Mail Account…
5.       Input your account information.
6.       Click Continue.
7.       Click Manual config.
8.       Set the Incoming settings as follows:
          a.       Server hostname: imap-mail.outlook.com.
          b.      Port: 993.
          c.       SSL: SSL/TLS.
          d.      Authentication: Normal password.

9.       Set the Outgoing settings as follows:  
          a.       Server hostname: smtp-mail.outlook.com.
          b.      Port: 587.
          c.       SSL: STARTTLS.
          d.      Authentication: Normal password.

10.   Click Done.
```

The description is from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/how-to-set-up-thunderbird-to-sync-your-outlookcom/266ddd8f-250c-4e8a-9799-009d992be8e3). If that doesn't work explain what errors you are receiving?

Comment: Login to server smtp-mail.outlook.com failed.

Comment: it also suggests i re enter my password which i carefully do but that doesn't work either

Comment: Are you putting username@outlook.com or just username for your account name?

Comment: my email address

Comment: a rep from Outlook just walked me through all the settings and could not find anything wrong

Comment: there does not appear to be any email or phone support for TB that I can find

Comment: Still having issues? Made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into settings for the smtp outgoing server and change the port to 25 and try it. Try sending an email. Then try port 465. They will both attempt to connect rather than say it cant find smtp-mail.outlook.com. After that switch it back to port 587. Hopefully it works then. Mine Did. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two-step verification enabled on your account, you need to create a new app password and use that for authentication with thunderbird.
Login into outlook -> go to your microsoft account settings -> security -> App passwords -> Create a new app password

Reasoning:

> Some apps and devices (such as Xbox 360, Windows Phone, or mail apps
> on your other devices) don't support security codes for two-step
> verification. In these cases, you need to create an app password to
> sign in. Learn more about app passwords.

Answer (score 0):

log in to Outlook.
Upper right-click on the circle with your profile image. After that, go to security. Now click on Advanced Security Options. In App passwords, click Create a new app password and now insert the generated code to Thunderbird.
I think that you have to generate one password for each app you face this problem. I had the same problem with you and I have two-step verification activated.

(the idea of what was going on was given to me by David and I search it a bit)